# align bottom not working properlly in relative layout

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

While running application layout not displaying properly

I am trying to show author text view below the quote text view

but it's not working

**XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/black"
    tools:context=".PreviewActivity">

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/lnimg"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/contact_number"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgquote"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/quote"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/album_title_padding"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/album_title_padding"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:text="Quotes"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:typeface="serif"
        android:textSize="@dimen/_15sdp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/author"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="end"
        android:layout_below="@+id/quote"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/album_title_padding"
        android:text=" -Author"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="@dimen/_15sdp" />
</RelativeLayout>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imgsave"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/circle"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/_5sdp"
    android:padding="@dimen/_5sdp"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_download"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I've done this type of layout before but it's not working now

I am getting this output

[image]

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: you sure? i check it in my android studio and work fine!
did you change something in java?

Comment: relative layout "lnimg" should be match-parent and make imageview "imgsave" above relative layout "lnimg"

Comment: in android studio preview showing right but while running app it's not showing properly

Comment: are you using different layout for HDPI,MDI,XHDP for other?

Comment: I am using the default layout

Comment: thank you all for help I got the perfect output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solve the problem

Just move Textview in vertical LinearLayout

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/quote"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/album_title_padding"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/album_title_padding"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/album_title_padding"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:text="Quotes"
        android:typeface="serif"
        android:textSize="@dimen/_15sdp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/author"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="end"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/album_title_padding"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/album_title_padding"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/album_title_padding"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_10sdp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/_5sdp"
        android:text=" -Author"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="@dimen/_15sdp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your TextViews as below , It will work perfectly..

```
  <TextView
            android:id="@+id/quote"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="To Sccesssed in life you \n things a wishbone, a backbone  and \n a funny bone."
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:typeface="serif" />

   <TextView
            android:id="@+id/author"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/quote"
            android:gravity="bottom|right"
            android:paddingRight="20dp"
            android:text=" -Author"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="15sp" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove this

```
android:layout_centerInParent="true"
```

from you quote TextView.

You can try this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/black"
    tools:context=".PreviewActivity">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/lnimg"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/contact_number"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgquote"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/quote"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/album_title_padding"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/album_title_padding"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:text="Quotes"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:typeface="serif"
            android:textSize="@dimen/_15sdp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/author"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="end"
            android:layout_below="@+id/quote"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/album_title_padding"
            android:text=" -Author"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="@dimen/_15sdp" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgsave"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/circle"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/_5sdp"
        android:padding="@dimen/_5sdp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_download"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```